# jQuery - fadeIn not working only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm working on a script which is hiding and showing some divs after some time.

Here is my complete jQuery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
        $("#SuperWebF1").click(function(){
        if ($('[name="shipping_method"]', window.parent.document).is(':checked')){
        billing.save();     
        $("#LoadingDiv", window.parent.document).show().delay(4300).fadeOut();
        $("#OutDiv", window.parent.document).hide().delay(5000).fadeIn();
        $('#OutDiv', window.parent.document).removeClass('outerdiv');
        $('#OutDiv', window.parent.document).removeClass('outerdivNoAdress');

        setTimeout(function() {
        if( $('#DisplayMe').length ){
           $('#OutDiv', window.parent.document).addClass('OuterDiv1000');
        } else {
           $('#OutDiv', window.parent.document).addClass('OuterDiv1000No');
        }
        }, 5100);


        $('#InnerIframe', window.parent.document).removeClass('FrameCSS');
        $('#InnerIframe', window.parent.document).removeClass('FrameCSSNoAdress');
        $('#InnerIframe', window.parent.document).addClass('FrameCSS1000');
    }else {
    alert('Моля, изберете начин на доставка!');
    }   

        })
    });
    </script>
```

The problem is in that line:

```
        $("#OutDiv", window.parent.document).hide().delay(5000).fadeIn();
```

After it hides the div with the line of code abouve this one it seems this line of code is not showing back the `#OutDiv` element.

I can confirm that i have this problem only with Firefox Mozilla.
Tested on Firefox on Windows and Linux and in the both places i have this problem.
Both browsers are up to date.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: can you make an example of this on jsfiddle that doesn't work on FF but works in Chrome / IE?

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
window.parent.$(elementid));
```

Comment: I don't get it. Please show me how my code must look like with this.

Comment: `code` window.parent.$("#LoadingDiv")).show().delay(4300).fadeOut(); `code`